# Rendering a view in different controller upon form (validation) error, while carring validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following problem with my first Rails application

First I used Scaffolding to generate a Patient entity.
However, I want the `Patient` addition form to be visible in my homepage, which is controlled by the controller `PagesController` and its action `Home`. I just rendered the partial view with the form of the `Patient` addition in my homepage.

After I submit the form, if the addition is succesful it works as it should. However, if validation fails, it gets me to patients/new (not to my homepage), displaying the form errors. This happens because of this code in the PatientsController

```
if @patient.save
    format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @patient, status: :created, location: @patient }
  else
    format.html { render action "new" }
    format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

Instead of this I want that in case of error it should get me back to the homepage (where the form was submitted) showing the errors. I tried doing the following:

```
format.html { render :controller => "pages", :action => "home" }
```

but I got this error

```
Missing template patients/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/xhorxhi91/Sites/dentarails/app/views"
```

Also I tried this:

```
format.html { render 'pages/home' }
```

this calls only the view, not the method `Home` so any objects that are created in that method are not recreated. Also the errors are not carried. I know I may recreate objects from my method but I know this is bad practice.

Also I know I cannot use the redirect_to method because the error messages will not be carried.

Any suggestions? I am new to Ruby so I am not sure also if my architecture is correct.

Answer (score 0):

if your routes.rb shows

`match 'pages/home' => "pages#home", as: "pages_home"`

then you could write

`format.html { render pages_home_path }`

Comment: Since it is a render method, it will not call the method 'home' of the 'Pages' controller, but simply render the view. However, I have several variables that I initialize in Pages#home and that are used in that view. That's why this is not working for me